# Propel - hidden columns

Tags: visibility, hidden, propel

I started using Propel to work with database.

I am missing something like hidden attributes. 
Is there something that prevents columns to be shown. 
For example, I don't want to show password when I write something like this

UserQuery::create()->find()->toJson()

Answer (score 1):

There is no feature of Propel that I have seen to support hiding the value of columns like this.  Hopefully you are storing a hash of the password in the database, instead of the plain text password.

To "hide" columns like this, I override the `toArray()` method of the `User` class.